# Bundle id starts with `org`

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bundle-identifier

I am trying to create the bundle id that starts with `org.help.msapp` in apple but I am not sure whether it's a valid bundle id or not.

I have explored the threads and come across the example that starts with `com` only. Never came across such bundle id example that has `org` or `edu` as prefix.

So the question is -  `org.foo.foopp` would be the valid identifire ?

Answer (score 1):

> A bundle ID uniquely identifies a single app throughout the system. The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.). The string should be in reverse-DNS format. Bundle IDs are case sensitive.

Since `org.help.msapp` is a valid reverse-DNS string, you should have no issues.

[Link to reference](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev91fe7130a) (click on the Bundle ID link in the first step)